# Difference between 'remote', 'local', and 'base' using p4merge

Tags: git, merge, p4merge

I'm merging my branch on the *master* branch using the `p4Merge` tool, and I see three views:

```
LOCAL
REMOTE
BASE
```

What are the differences between these views?

Comment: Why is a Perforce tool used for Git?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[This video tutorial](https://www.perforce.com/video-tutorials/resolving-conflicts) does a good job of explaining what each of these views mean:

> 4-pane merge tools show you these panes:
>
> - LOCAL – your file with the changes you’ve made to it
> - BASE – the common ancestor file that LOCAL and REMOTE came from
> - REMOTE – the file you’re merging in, possibly authored by someone else
> - MERGE_RESULT – the file resulting from the merge where you resolve conflicts

We could visualize the history of the file as follows:

```
remote: ... v1 -- v2 -- v3
                   \
local:              v4
```

Here `v3` would be the `REMOTE` version of file, and `v4` is the `LOCAL` version.  The `BASE` is `v2`, and the `MERGE_RESULT` is the file which would result from merging the remote into the local file.

Comment: link doesn't work. Please see here a short video tutorial from the company behind p4merge https://www.perforce.com/video-tutorials/resolving-conflicts

Comment: @kouretinho Thanks for letting us know that the link was down.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using [Sourcetree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlassian#Acquisitions_and_product_announcements) you can see the following. Which is what Tim suggested above.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
P -- B
 \
  A
```

```
git checkout A
git merge B    #merge B into A
```

- local = A
- remote = B
- base = P

I would add that on a rebase, local and remote are reversed.

```
P -- B
 \
  A
```

```
git checkout A
git rebase B    #rebase A onto B
```

- local = B
- remote = A
- base = P

Comment: "I would add that on a rebase, local and remote are reversed." That was what I was looking for, cheers!